# What is the name of Kotlin's !! operator

Tags: kotlin, terminology

When in a conversation with other developers, what do I call the `!!` operator?

In Kotlin, the `?:` is called the **Elvis operator**

These sources don't say what the name of `!!` is:

- http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator
- http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html

Looking online, the generic term for `!!` is **double bang**. Do I use the same for Kotlin even though swift's `!` operator is called **forced unwrapping** (Note: the `!` in swift is similar to Kotlin's `!!`.)

What I'm specifically looking for:

- A name that I can verbally call the `!!` operation that Kotlin developers can understand
- A name other than **double exclamation** or **bang bang** or **double bang**

Comment: Wow. Nice first question, and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: I personally like _bang bang_. It's short and to the point: if you use this, things are liable to explode.

Answer (score 30):

The [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) refers to it as `the not-null assertion operator`.

Personally, I call it the `hold my beer operator`.

Comment: I prefer `danger zone operator` :)

Comment: Todd, let me just tell you that out of all the ways to call it, your suggestion of the "Hold My Beer"-operator is my favorite one. It's fitting, because it's most often used as a phrase before the person yelling it is doing something stupid.

Answer (score 7):

"Kotlin in Action" calls it the not-null assertion operator. We've decided to update the docs to use this term too.

Answer (score 4):

I like to say **"non-null asserted call"** for things like

```
a!!.length
```

that is also how it is shown in the Android studio <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> context menu.

Makes sense to me because that sums up what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 4):

I use to call it "**double bang**", but actually `hold my beer operator` does get to the heart of it too (thx @Todd ;-)).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using "force-unwrapping" (same as is in Swift).

Comment: AFAIK Kotlin compiler still wraps such statement to provide more verbose exception than just simple Java’s NPE. It will be similar to NPE but will carry information like what class/method/code line was responsible for the NPE.