# Range of an Array or List in Kotlin when it does not have to accommodate the empty case

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, max, min

I'm looking to calculate the range of a list or array and was frustrated by not being able to simply take the difference of the `max()` and `min()` functions due to null safety feature of Kotlin.

I came up with this solution which is forcing me to deal with the case of an `ifEmpty()` even if I know that is not possible in with this immutable array.  I wonder if there is something simpler without the extra characters.

```
val array=arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
// doesn't compile... val range = array.max()-array.min()
val range = (array.max() ?: 0) - (array.min() ?: 0)
```

Comment: You may want to use fold instead of calling min and max separately, depending on how much overhead looping over the list twice adds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't much different, but since you *know* that it isn't empty, you can use `!!` ([the Hold My Beer operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47543386/49746)), to tell Kotlin to ignore the nullability of the types.

```
val range = if(array.isEmpty()) 0 else array.max()!! - array.min()!!
```

It might also be handy to define an extension if you anticipate doing this a lot:

```
fun Array<Int>.range(): Int = 
    if(isEmpty()) 0 else max()!! - min()!!

// Usage
val range = array.range()
```