# Kotlin reduce has limitations?

Tags: list, kotlin, filter, reduce

I would like to implement the same following code, using the reduce method. I know this is possible in other languages, but I don't know how to achieve it in Kotlin

```
class A
class B (val a: A?)

fun test(listOfBs: List<B>): List<A> {
    return listOfBs.filter { it.a != null }.map { it.a!! }
    // TODO return listOfBs.reduce { ??? }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `filter` and then `map`, you can use [`mapNotNull` from the Kotlin Standard Library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html). This function combines the two and you can avoid the [Hold My Beer operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543419/49746) (`!!`).

Example:

```
fun test(listOfBs: List<B>): List<A> = 
    listOfBs.mapNotNull { it.a }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html#parameters) in Kotlin is not suitable for this. It is declared like this:

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

Notice how it can only return an `S`, which is a super type of the element type `T`. This means that you can't `reduce` a `List<B>` to a `List<A>`.

In "other languages", you can specify an "identity element" when reducing, and you probably also want to do that. In Kotlin, you can do that with [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

```
fun test(listOfBs: List<B>): List<A> =
        listOfBs.fold(emptyList()) { acc, b ->
            if (b.a != null) {
                acc + listOf(b.a) // this is very bad code, it creates a bunch of unnecessary lists
            } else {
                acc
            }
        }
```

But of course, "mapping only if not null" is a common enough thing to do that it is already built into the Kotlin Standard Library - `mapNotNull`:

```
fun test(listOfBs: List<B>): List<A> =
        listOfBs.mapNotNull { it.a }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at how `reduce` is implemented in the Kotlin standard library:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html